# In Terminal, when the the “cd” command is called, libwww-perl's “head” command is also executed

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

Currently, in Terminal, when I execute a `cd` command, it also executes LWP's `head` command.

A copy of the Terminal output follows:

```
laptop:bin user$ cd ~
Unknown option: n
Usage: head [-options] <url>...
    -m <method>   use method for the request (default is 'HEAD')
    -f            make request even if head believes method is illegal
    -b <base>     Use the specified URL as base
    -t <timeout>  Set timeout value
    -i <time>     Set the If-Modified-Since header on the request
    -c <conttype> use this content-type for POST, PUT, CHECKIN
    -a            Use text mode for content I/O
    -p <proxyurl> use this as a proxy
    -P            don't load proxy settings from environment
    -H <header>   send this HTTP header (you can specify several)

    -u            Display method and URL before any response
    -U            Display request headers (implies -u)
    -s            Display response status code
    -S            Display response status chain
    -e            Display response headers
    -d            Do not display content
    -o <format>   Process HTML content in various ways

    -v            Show program version
    -h            Print this message

    -x            Extra debugging output
laptop:bin user$
```

I've reviewed the `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc` but there are only three export statements and no alias or something like that. It's as follows:

```
[[ -s "/Users/user/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/Users/user/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM into a shell session.
### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=/Users/user/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.2.342:$PATH
export SENCHA_CMD_3_0_0="/Users/user/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.2.342"
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/acquia-drupal/drush
```

From reading, it seems that installing LWP might have overwritten the `/usr/bin/head` command, but I've checked and it's the OSX one. However, when I call `head` from Terminal, it invokes the LWP head command instead.

Per patrix's request, here are the contents of `~/.rvm/scripts/rvm`: http://pastebin.com/7rZVQAcy

I'll keep out trying things, and I'll update the question with new information if relevant.

Additional information:

```
laptop:dir user$ alias cd
-bash: alias: cd: not found
laptop:dir user$ which cd
/usr/bin/cd
laptop:dir user$ which head
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/head
```

The output of `echo "$PS1"; echo "$PROMPT_COMMAND"` is:

```
\h:\W \u\$ 
update_terminal_cwd;
```

The output of `type -a update_terminal_cwd` is:

```
update_terminal_cwd is a function
update_terminal_cwd () 
{ 
    local SEARCH=' ';
    local REPLACE='%20';
    local PWD_URL="file://$HOSTNAME${PWD//$SEARCH/$REPLACE}";
    printf '\e]7;%s\a' "$PWD_URL"
}
```

The output of `type -a cd` is:

```
cd is a function
cd () 
{ 
    if builtin cd "$@"; then
        __rvm_do_with_env_before;
        __rvm_project_rvmrc;
        __rvm_after_cd;
        __rvm_do_with_env_after;
        return 0;
    else
        return $?;
    fi
}
cd is a shell builtin
cd is /usr/bin/cd
```

Comment: What is in `/Users/user/.rvm/scripts/rvm`?

Comment: @patrix, edited question to include that file's content, thanks!

Comment: what does `alias cd` and `which cd` show?

Comment: @Esteban, In terminal type `which head` then post the result here. That should tell the path of which one you're actually using.

Comment: Ok, so it seems it's using head from XAMPP, however, why would that fire every time I use "cd" to move to a different directory? It does the directory change but then immediately fires off the head help message due to incorrect usage. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: What is the output of `echo "$PS1"; echo "$PROMPT_COMMAND"`?

Comment: @glennjackman, it outputs:
\h:\W \u\$ 
update_terminal_cwd;

Comment: what is update_terminal_cwd? `type -a update_terminal_cwd`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to assume you are using `bash`.

So in that case when you just type `cd` it should be running the bash built-in. This is what has the problem.

To confirm this try using the external version - at the command prompt type `/usr/bin/cd` and you should go to your home directory with no problems.

Now let's check what the other `cd` might be up to.

`type -a cd` should give us

```
cd is a shell builtin
cd is /usr/bin/cd
```

`which head` should give us `/usr/bin/head`

`alias` might give us a long list but nothing pointing towards an alias for `cd`

The CD environment variables should have sane entries:

```
CDARGS_NODUPS=1
CDARGS_SORT=0
CDPATH='.:~:~/bin:~/dev:/usr:/'
```

The same with:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a; history -n; printf "\e]1;${PWD}\a"'
PS1='\[\033[34m\]\h:\W \u$\[\033[0m\] '
SHELLOPTS=braceexpand:emacs:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor
```

If all that is OK then my money would be on `cd` being redefined by a builtin function that has gone pear shaped. At the command line `set | less` will allow you to page through a dump of all your shell variables, aliases and functions. If you type `/` you can search through the file for `cd` (notice the space) and see if that is happening.

Once you have discovered that "someone" - in your case `rvm` - is defining a shell function called `cd` then you can either uninstall the culprit or find where it does the nasty work and change the name of the function to something like 'rcd' instead of 'cd'. As the shell function is listed first in the output of `type` the builtin `cd` is ignored except where it is getting called by the function (that's what the `builtin cd` in the function definition is doing - calling the builtin version).

I'd almost guarantee that the function is defined in `/Users/user/.rvm/scripts/rvm`.

I'd start by uninstalling `rvm` and then reinstall to see if that fixes it. Are you installing it using MacPorts or Homebrew?

Comment: I think, based on the first command `type -a cd` we've got part of the culprit, as I'm getting something from RVM as well as the builtin shell function (added output to question). So I believe it's calling both? How would one fix that so it's not using those two cd definitions?

Comment: Uninstalling fixed the issues (especially following RVM's instructions to remove all traces of it from the system) It was installed using Homebrew.

Comment: Nice. RVM was actually my first thought when I read the description. Just get rbenv, it only aliases the ruby commands and therefor shouldn't mess with anything else.